# How to talk with ABP API from windows service

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

This is what I would like to build. A hosted web/api project built on APB where tenants can use the web application to define "Scan Definitions" that run inside their network. A scan definition would just contain a target IP Address to be scanned with WMI. They would download and install a windows service that would run periodically in their network. The service would communicate with the APB web API to retrieve scan definitions, then run the scan and upload the resulting scan data into the APB web API. Then the users would be able to view that scan data within the web app.

My question is with the CORS access in place, how can I make it so that the windows service is allowed to talk with the API. Also what is the best way to authenticate the service with api such that the service would know which tenant it should be using so that it pulls down the correct scan definitions and uploads the data to the correct tenant as well.

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a service up and running by following the abp sample found here: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/tree/master/ConsoleRemoteWebApiCall/CallApiFromConsole

I still have things to work through, but it's gotten me to a spot where I can access the api from a console application